# how to make product listing page for mobile devices?

Tags: html, media

I am trying to make a html page to display different product for my sample e-commerce website, but on mobile devices it is not displayed properly on some phones image is getting bigger and on some other product details are getting bigger.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT82O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lalJb.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're making an app that will be displayed on multiple devices, then I highly suggest you take the time to learn/use some Bootstrap as it allows for responsive design.

http://getbootstrap.com/ should get you started.